# How to restart a task elegantly?

Tags: c#, task, tcpclient, task-parallel-library, tcplistener

So I have something like this:

`Task.Factory.FromAsync<TcpClient>(tcpListener.BeginAcceptTcpClient, tcpListener.EndAcceptTcpClient, tcpListener).ContinueWith(ConnectionAccepted);`

```
private void ConnectionAccepted(Task<TcpClient> tcpClientTask)
{
    TcpClient tcpClient = tcpClientTask.Result;

    // Do something with tcpClient
}
```

Now I'm wondering, how can I initiate `Task.Factory.FromAsync<TcpClient>(...)` again at the end of this method? I can't really just copy and paste the line of code because I don't have access to TcpListener and would rather not make it a member variable. Even if I did though, it's such a long line of code it kinda feels like code duplication to me.

Does the Tasks framework provide some sort of mechanism to accomplish this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As svick suggested, the easiest way would be to make `tcpListener` in to a field. But if for some reason you can't do that, try this pattern:

```
void AcceptClient()
{
    // Create tcpListener here.
    AcceptClientImpl(tcpListener);
}

void AcceptClientImpl(TcpListener tcpListener)
{
    Task.Factory.FromAsync<TcpClient>(tcpListener.BeginAcceptTcpClient, tcpListener.EndAcceptTcpClient, tcpListener).ContinueWith(antecedent =>
    {
        ConnectionAccepted(antecedent.Result);

        // Restart task by calling AcceptClientImpl "recursively".
        // Note, this is called from the thread pool. So no stack overflows.
        AcceptClientImpl(tcpListener);
    });
}

void ConnectionAccepted(TcpClient tcpClient)
{
    // Do stuff here.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is anything in the Framework for restarting `Task`s.

But your problem can be trivially solved by putting the `tcpListener` into a field and putting the line that creates the task into a method, so there won't be any code duplication.